# How to get userInfo through google idToken

Tags: go, google-api, google-oauth

Now I hava a google Idtoken, I want to get the user information through the token,
from this page I found how to verify and get the tokenInfo,
[Validating Google sign in ID token in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716117/validating-google-sign-in-id-token-in-go/36717411#36717411)
but the tokenInfo doesn't contain user picture.
what should I do to get the user information?

Comment: The user info end point or the google people api https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtaininguserprofileinformation

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks for your reply. In the webpage you provided, I request the user info must with access token, but I only can obtain the id_token from front end, I reference from this link: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

Comment: Userinfo end point doesn't work with an Id token?  what kind of response is it returning?

Comment: try this endpoint https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get send **me** for the userid  You can also decode the id token some of the stuff should be in the claims https://jwt.io/

Comment: I decode the idToken.payload the get others information.

Comment: You might want to edit your question and your anwser and include the code you used it may help someone else someday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

id_token is a jwt. I first use [validating-google-sign-in-id-token-in-go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716117/validating-google-sign-in-id-token-in-go) to check the token is vailed.

```
authService, err := oauth2.New(http.DefaultClient)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
// check token is valid
tokenInfoCall := authService.Tokeninfo()
tokenInfoCall.IdToken(idToken)
ctx, cancelFunc := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 1*time.Minute)
defer cancelFunc()
tokenInfoCall.Context(ctx)
tokenInfo, er := tokenInfoCall.Do()
if err != nil {
    // invalid token
}
```

Then I parse the id_token as jwt, decode the payload to json.

```
token, _, err := new(jwt.Parser).ParseUnverified(idToken, &TokenInfo{})
if tokenInfo, ok := token.Claims.(*TokenInfo); ok {
    return tokenInfo, nil
} else {
    // parse token.payload failed
}

// TokenInfo struct
type TokenInfo struct {
        Iss string `json:"iss"`
    // userId
    Sub string `json:"sub"`
    Azp string `json:"azp"`
    // clientId
    Aud string `json:"aud"`
    Iat int64  `json:"iat"`
    // expired time
    Exp int64 `json:"exp"`

    Email         string `json:"email"`
    EmailVerified bool   `json:"email_verified"`
    AtHash        string `json:"at_hash"`
    Name          string `json:"name"`
    GivenName     string `json:"given_name"`
    FamilyName    string `json:"family_name"`
    Picture       string `json:"picture"`
    Local         string `json:"locale"`
    jwt.StandardClaims
}
```

the value like:

```
{
 // These six fields are included in all Google ID Tokens.
 "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
 "sub": "110169484474386276334",
 "azp": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "aud": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "iat": "1433978353",
 "exp": "1433981953",

 // These seven fields are only included when the user has granted the "profile" and
 // "email" OAuth scopes to the application.
 "email": "testuser@gmail.com",
 "email_verified": "true",
 "name" : "Test User",
 "picture": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kYgzyAWpZzJ/ABCDEFGHI/AAAJKLMNOP/tIXL9Ir44LE/s99-c/photo.jpg",
 "given_name": "Test",
 "family_name": "User",
 "locale": "en"
}
```

then I get the picture.

Comment: This works.

Adding `jwt.StandardClaims` to `type TokenInfo struct` is key.